# Can not open an existing page in XAMPP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, xampp, htdocs

I have a problem with opening an PHP file in Xampp.I get a whole page to make some changes to it.So I just put whole page folder, with all files, in htdocs and then, when i try to  access folder with that file, via browser, I get this:

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'hospital_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in D:\xampp\htdocs\hospital\public_html\config.php on line 15
Connect failed: Access denied for user 'hospital_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I try to test an hello world php file and it works.Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Your database configuration is wrong. 
Open `D:\xampp\htdocs\hospital\public_html\config.php` and write correct username and password.